# elasticsearch .net client completion suggester performance

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

For some requests using the Nest or the Elasticsearch.Net client the response time is above 500ms. 
When using an http client directly or threw kibana interface the same query takes about 1-2ms.
This happens event if there are very few documents in the data base.

I am using the following settings on localhost:

```
PUT suggestions
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "suggestionelement": {
      "properties": {
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "max_input_length": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And indexing the following documents:

```
POST suggestions/suggestionelement
{
  "suggest": {
    "input": "this is just some text for suggestion a",
    "weight": 1
  }
}

POST suggestions/suggestionelement
{
  "suggest": {
    "input": "this is just some text for suggestion b",
    "weight": 2
  }
}

POST suggestions/suggestionelement
{
  "suggest": {
    "input": "this is just some text for suggestion c",
    "weight": 3
  }
}

POST suggestions/suggestionelement
{
  "suggest": {
    "input": "this is just some text for suggestion d",
    "weight": 4
  }
}

POST suggestions/suggestionelement
{
  "suggest": {
    "input": "this is just some text for suggestion e",
    "weight": 5
  }
}
```

When running a suggest(completion) query for "this is just some text for" threw the Nest or Elasticsearch.Net clients, it takes more than 500ms.
Running the same from kibana or directly with httpclient takes less then 2ms

Been at it for days... any ideas?

C# code im using:

```
        var nodes = new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") };
        var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);

        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
           .DefaultIndex("suggestions")
           .RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        var searchEngineClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            return await searchEngineClient.SearchAsync<SuggestionElement>(s =>
                s.Suggest(ss => ss
                    .Completion("sentence-suggest", c => c
                    .Field(f => f.Suggest)
                    .Prefix("this is just some text for")
                    .Size(1000))));
        };
```

Comment: Can you show the C# code which performs this query? Do you experience such slowdown only with the first query via NEST or every request evaluates too slow?

Comment: I added the c# code to the original post... this is not just for the first request, and as you can see i am using the same client over and over.

Comment: What about using `SingleNodeConnectionPool` instead of `StaticConnectionPool`?

Comment: @RussCam i did try with SingleConnectionPool, no luck